# "error reading from connection" on loading package on UNIX

Tags: r, package, require

I am working on a linux cluster. I installed required R packages in a local library created in my home directory. Till yesterday everything was fine. but suddenly today I am not able to
load those packages in my local library. the error is "error reading from the connection".
That directory id present. All package are inside the directory and my path is also correct. I don't understand wht is the problem. please help me. this is how i am loading the package.

```
require("doMC",lib.loc = "~/Rlibrary")
```

Comment: How about setting `R_LIBS` in `.Renviron`?

Comment: Thanks for reply, but i deleted local library and reinstalled those packages. It is working fine now but this is not a solution. I don't know how to do what you are suggesting.

Comment: This [link](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Startup.html) is a good starting point.